# Update a List element based on a HashMap value/key

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have the ArrayList:

```java
List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
// [eu, quero, voltar, para, praia, e, comer, queijo]
```

And the HashMap:

```java
Map<String, String> wordsMap = new HashMap<>();
//{v.=voltar, c.=comer, q.=queijo., p.=praia}
```

I am trying to do: If the list element is equal to map value, then replace the list element by the map **key**. In this example, the result would be:

```java
// [eu, quero, v., para, p., e, c., q.]
```

Something that I tried was

```java
      for (String word : wordsList) {
         for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : wordsMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            if (word.equals(value)) {
               newWordsList.add(key);
            } else {
               newWordsList.add(word);
            }
         }
      }
Result: [eu, eu, eu, eu, quero, quero, quero, quero, v., voltar, voltar, voltar, para, para, para, para, praia, praia, praia, p., e, e, e, e, comer, c., comer, comer, queijo, queijo, q., queijo]
```

Any help?? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step for me would be to create a new map that uses the value as key and the key as value. That is much easier than looping through the old map and checking for values.

```
Map<String, String> invertedWordsMap = wordsMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collecotrs.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue), Map.Entry::getKey));
//{voltar=v., comer=c., queijo=q.., praia=p.}
```

And then I just have to check if the key exists in the map

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {
    String word = invertedWordsMap.get(wordsList.get(i));
    if (word != null) {
        wordsList.set(i, word);
    }
}
```

And here is the obligatory  fancy stream answer. Just keep in mind that the old list is replaced and not changed if you use the stream solution.

```
wordsList = wordsList.stream().map(word -> invertedWordsMap.getOrDefault(word, word)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No external dependencies to get the same effect as my answer... +1 didn't think of that :)

Comment: Really nice and clean solution! Thanks a lot!! I also have tried to use streams but I kinda get lost so I gave up on it hehe.

Comment: If you get started with streams they can be a bit overwhelming, but with a bit of practice they are really handy :)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash The parameters are the same but the result is different. `getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)` is basically doing this: `if (map.get(key) != null) { return map.get(key); } else { return defaultValue; }`

Comment: @magicmn - Fab! I know how `getOrDefault` works but somehow I missed to interpret it in the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate the `wordsMap.entrySet()`, find the index of the `entry#value` in `wordsList`, and update `wordsList` at the index with the `entry#key`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>(
                List.of("eu", "quero", "voltar", "para", "praia", "e", "comer", "queijo."));
        Map<String, String> wordsMap = Map.of("v.", "voltar", "c.", "comer", "q.", "queijo.", "p.", "praia");

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : wordsMap.entrySet()) {
            int index = wordsList.indexOf(entry.getValue());
            if (index != -1) {
                wordsList.set(index, entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(wordsList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[eu, quero, v., para, p., e, c., q.]
```

**Note:** [`List#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or `-1` if this list does not contain the element. Therefore the logic in the solution given above checks for `-1` and also, only the first occurrence of the matching value will be replaced. If your list has duplicate elements and you want all occurrences of the matching value to be replaced, you need to find all indices of the matching value and replace them as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("eu", "quero", "queijo.", "voltar", "queijo.", "para", "praia",
                "e", "queijo.", "comer", "queijo."));
        Map<String, String> wordsMap = Map.of("v.", "voltar", "c.", "comer", "q.", "queijo.", "p.", "praia");
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : wordsMap.entrySet()) {
            List<Integer> allIndices = allIndicesOf(wordsList, entry.getValue());
            for (int index : allIndices) {
                wordsList.set(index, entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(wordsList);
    }

    static List<Integer> allIndicesOf(List<String> list, String str) {
        return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .boxed()
                .filter(i -> list.get(i).equals(str))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[eu, quero, q., v., q., para, p., e, q., c., q.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the list and the map:

```
List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList("eu", "quero", "voltar", "para", "praia", "e", "comer", "queijo");
Map<String, String> wordsMap = Map.of("v.", "voltar", "c.", "comer", "q.", "queijo", "p.", "praia");
```

Then the code below returns your results (without any external dependency):

```
// If the list element is equal to map value, then replace the list element
// by the map key.In this example, the result would be:

wordsMap.values().stream()
    // If the list contains the map value
    .filter(wordsList::contains)
    .forEach(value -> {
        // Find the corresponding map key
        String mapKey = wordsMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), value))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // It could find several keys if you have the same value for different keys
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(); // It should never happen as we are looping in the map values

        // Find the index and update the list with the map key
        int index = wordsList.indexOf(value);
        wordsList.set(index, mapKey);
    });

System.out.println(wordsList);
// [eu, quero, v., para, p., e, c., q.]
```

Comment: Nice that it uses no other dependencies. I find streams aren't very easy to read though so I personally don't use them often.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a google HashBiMap<String, String> because it can provide an inverse view of the same map, i.e. In a `Map<K,V>` you can do both `get(K) returns V` and `get(V) returns K`

```java
        // Form the words list
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        wordsList.add("eu");
        wordsList.add("quero");
        // etc adding all of the terms you mentioned

        // Form the keyset
        HashBiMap<String, String> wordsMap = HashBiMap.create();
        wordsMap.put("v", "voltar");
        wordsMap.put("c", "comer");
        // etc adding all the terms you mentioned

        List<String> wordsListOut = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Iterating through the wordsList
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {

            // Get the current element
            String element = wordsList.get(i);
            // Does it have an inverse pair?
            String result = wordsMap.inverse().get(element);

            // If it has an inverse pair, add the inverse key. Otherwise, add the element raw.
            wordsListOut.add(result == null ? element : result);

        }

        // Outputs: [eu, quero, v, para, p, e, c, q]
        System.out.println(wordsListOut);
```

The dependency for HashBiMap is Google Guava:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note: Similarly to @Thibaut Ledent's answer, adding "q2, queijo" to the map leads to an illegal argument exception (duplicate value already present: queijo)